# Running a Powershell foreach loop and print results in groups

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script that puts a list of relevant file Paths in $hits, which I've used foreach on to print:

1. The pattern it matched on;
2. The file the match occurred in;
3. The line it was found in, and
4. The timestamps for that file.

```bsh
ForEach ($item in $hits) {
    $match = Get-ItemProperty ($item.Path)
    Write-Host "Match found for string" $item.Pattern "in" $item.Path "in line" $item.Line `n "> File Created" $match.CreationTime `n "> Last Written" $match.LastWriteTime `n "> Last Accessed" $match.LastAccessTime
}
```

Producing a result like this:

> Match found for string foo in C:\Test\foobar.txt in line bar 
>   File Created 29/07/2019 5:56:04 PM 
>   Last Written 29/07/2019 5:57:58 PM 
>   Last Accessed 29/07/2019 5:56:04 PM

The problem is when I find a file with multiple lines with the string "foo" in them, the script prints a result for every line within that file.

How can I iterate over the $hits list and get the results to print just once per file, listing the individual pattern matches within the file?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `Group-Object -Property Path`.

Comment: Before foreach: $hits = $hits | Select-Object -Unique